# MySQL Notifier Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm getting an error when opening Mysql notifier:

> **High Severity Error** Element 'UpdateCheck' was not found. Line 3, position 2.

My MySQL server is running. Why is it showing this error?

Answer (score 3):

The error appears due to a corrupted configuration file or some dummy MySQL services (Leftovers from server installations not completely removed, this is due to the auto-detect mysql services functionality). Please **make sure** you're **running** the **latest Notifier** version available (that can be downloaded at [mysql downloads page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)).

**How to solve the corrupted file configuration:**

1. See the answer from Colin Pickard.

**How to solve the dummy MySQL services leftovers:**

1. If the problem persists, open a Run command window and type the following:

   > `services.msc`
2. Take note of any MySQL service that shouldn't be listed (attempted uninstall before).
3. Open an Admin rights command window and type the command:

   > sc delete "< Dummy_service_name_here >".

Restart Notifier and see if that corrected the problem.

If a similar error still appears afterwards, check if the stack trace shows the word CreateScheduledTask somewhere, that would mean something is wrong when Notifier tries to add a schedule task at startup to check for updates of any installed MySQL product.

A workaround is to open in notepad the `settings.config` file that was re-generated. Inside the file, look for a property called `"AutoCheckForUpdates"` and change the default value of `"True"` for `"False"` and run Notifier again, as noted in [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,605658,605696#msg-605696).

Answer (score 0):

I had this with Notifier 1.0.3.  I uninstalled it and downloaded the new installer for the 5.7 Alpha and used that to install Notifier 1.1.4, which now works fine for me.

You can get the download here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.7.html#downloads